# Kubernetes Undo Termination of PV

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, volume

I have mistakenly deleted PVs of kubernetes. However it shows terminating status. I want all PVs back without data lost. so that again it give status of Bound and get normal like before.

Comment: Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337900/7743705

Comment: Are you using what kind of persistenvolumes?

Comment: I am using GKE @KoopaKiller

Comment: I have tried that way but not worked. @DhruvShah

Comment: But you can see the disk in `Compute Engine > Disk`? Have you tried to take a snapshot ?